# ADB commands work on phone zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Tags: android, adb

I need to bind two folders, that I normally do with ADB from a computer with USB connection. But when I run out of battery or phone reboots, that would clear the binding. I don't want to have the two folders bound all the time so making something start in init is not a solution.

I want to execute root, remount, and bind the same way I do it via ADB and USB connection to PC. Is there an apk or what can do this to achieve same result within the phone. No pc no USB cable?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your phone is rooted already, otherwise you wouldn't be able to "execute root" anyway.

You can just run your commands in any terminal emulator on the phone, such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm). You can use `su` to become root and then issue your `mount` command they usual way.

To do this automatically, you can also use an app like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and create a task that runs this command for you (you'll have to tick "Use root"). Then you can additionally also set a trigger to run this task when you start the phone.

Comment: thans but su gives me Permission denied

Comment: Then please edit your question and describe in detail what you normally do. Because I would have expected it to work based on that you wrote that you can already get root.